# Dexie's Table.orderBy for Uint32Array orders as if it was Uint8Array

Tags: indexeddb, arraybuffer, dexie

My stored object has a timestamp in seconds since Unix epoch. I want to be able to store it as a Uint32Array and then retrieve it ordered by timestamp.

I use Dexie's Table.orderBy to retrieve it. The ordering is not correct and after some investigation I noticed that the order is as if you convert the Uint32Array to a Uint8Array.

See this fiddle example for how it fails to order by Uint32 and orders instead by Uint8:

https://fiddle.jshell.net/3tf5r0cu/708/

Am I making wrong assumptions or is it a flaw in Dexie or is it a flaw in IndexedDb?

I am using Dexie 2.0.1 in Chromium.

Answer (score 1):

It's according to the indexedDB 2.0 specification actually. All binary keys (any ArrayBufferView) is sorted equally (as a byte array). You should probably use numbers or Dates instead.

Comment: Thanks. I had read it without registering it but I take it that you are referring to this clause in the specification: _Members of binary keys are compared as unsigned octet values (in the range [0, 255]) rather than signed byte values (in the range [-128, 127])._